# How to find all indices of a given element in an array?

Tags: ruby

This code is supposed to add the indices of the word `'hello'` to the `indices` array, but it's not adding them to the array:

```
words = %w(hello how are you then okay then hello how)

def global(arg1, arg2)
  indices = []
  arg1.each do |x, y|
    indices << y if arg2 == x
  end
  indices
end

global(words,'hello')
#=> [nil, nil]
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `if arg1 == x` - an array will never equal one of its elements, so this condition is never true. That's why you get no indices. Did you mean `if arg2 == x`?

Comment: If you had better, more descriptive names for your arguments, this bug wouldn't have happened.

Comment: Also, `each_with_index` instead of `each`.

Comment: Following on Sergio's comment: with `each` you can only access the value, not the index, so `y` will always be `nil`; `each_with_index` will give you the value and the index (in that order).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some other ways to skin the cat.

Traverse [`each_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-each_index) and [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-select) the ones whose element match the searched word:

```
def indices(words, searched_word)
  words.each_index.select { |index| words[index] == searched_word }
end
```

Traverse each word along with its index ([`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)) and store the index in an explicit `indices` array if the word matches. Then return the `indices` array:

```
def indices(words, searched_word)
  indices = []
  words.each_with_index do |word, index|
    indices << index if word == searched_word
  end
  indices
end
```

Same as above, but pass the explicit array right into the iteration via [`with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) (which will also return that array):

```
def indices(words, searched_word)
  words.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(word, index), indices|
    indices << index if word == searched_word
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def indices(words, searched_word)
  words.each_with_index.select { |word, _| word == searched_word }.map(&:last)
end

words = %w(hello how are you then okay then hello how)

indices words, 'hello' # => [0, 7]
```