# Find a string index of a Ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing

Example, consider the list below:

```
list = ['k', 'bac', 'a', 'a', 'zBy', 'yUk', 'A', 'u', 'a']
```

I search this list for the index of 'a'.

Therefore, the expected return would be:

```
>>[1, 2, 3, 8]
```

However, I'm just getting the return of [2, 3, 8], because my function doesn't consider the char inside the string 'bac'.

My ideia:

```
 list.each_index.select{|i| list[i] == value}
```

Where am I going wrong? Thank you all. I'm learning a lot here!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659696/find-indices-of-elements-that-match-a-given-condition

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45499614/6045800

Comment: My problem is that I need to implement code that takes an *array* and looks for all the positions where a target character can be found. However, this code will be a function that will be able to find these indexes in several other lists, and each list wants the return of a different element, etc.
(It's a study challenge).

Comment: I edited the question, as I think my doubt was not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

> `list = ['k', 'z', 't', 'c', 'z', 'y', 'x', 'xay']`
> I would like to find the index of the `"z"` element in this list, it would return like this: `#=> [1,4]`

You can walk through the indexes of your array with `each_index` then `select` the ones that satisfy your condition:

```rb
list.each_index.select{|i| list[i] == ?z} #=> [1, 4]
```

---

**Update (bis)**

> My problem is that I need to implement code that takes an array and looks for all the positions where a target character can be found.

If you want to select the index of, for example, `'baz'` when looking for the character `'z'`, then you can just use `String#include?` in your condition:

```rb
"baz".include? 'z' #=> true
```

> However, this code will be a function that will be able to find these indexes in several other lists, and each list wants the return of a different element, etc.

Just wrap the previous code in a function:

```rb
def myfunction arr, c
  arr.each_index.select{|i| arr[i].include? c}
end
```

Comment: I edited the question, as I think my doubt was not very clear.

Comment: That was exactly it! How exciting haha ​​thank you very much! I'll never forget this .include